# Просуммировать список и поделить каждое значение одновременно

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.
Имеется следующая задача: с помощью reduce (выбор пал на него, но возможно это не верно) просуммировать отношения 1/y, где y - элемент list

можно предварительно провести операцию деления и получится очевидно:

```
pers_of_coef = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), coef_arr)
```

но хотелось бы уместить все в одну строку.
Следующее выражение не работает корректно:

```
pers_of_coef = reduce((lambda x, y: x + (1/y)), coef_arr)
```

Как я понял, в данном решении x - первый элемент, и он не нормируется (1/x), как следствие есть вариант вставить на 0 позицию list нуль, но подобный вариант тоже не кажется оптимальным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [356]: lst
Out[356]: [67, 11, 72, 39, 3, 20, 71, 66, 33, 4, 34, 92, 69, 52, 72, 4, 42, 93, 43, 13]

In [357]: sum(1./y for y in lst)
Out[357]: 1.3108716089277184
```

а лучше используйте Numpy:

```
In [349]: import numpy as np

In [350]: a = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(20))

In [351]: a
Out[351]: array([67, 11, 72, 39,  3, 20, 71, 66, 33,  4, 34, 92, 69, 52, 72,  4, 42, 93, 43, 13])

In [352]: 1./a
Out[352]:
array([0.01492537, 0.09090909, 0.01388889, 0.02564103, 0.33333333, 0.05      , 0.01408451, 0.01515152, 0.03030303, 0.25      , 0.02941176, 0.01086957, 0.01449275, 0.01923077, 0.01388889, 0.25      ,
       0.02380952, 0.01075269, 0.02325581, 0.07692308])

In [355]: np.sum(1./a)
Out[355]: 1.3108716089277184
```